# How to make your application available as a printer on Select Printer option of Print extension iOS

Tags: ios

Use-Case : User navigates to any url on safari page, taps on the share button and can share the pdf file of the safari page through the app. Eg: iBooks, iPrint

Open safari, go to any link and tap on share button. Then go to Apple's Print extension which will automatically generate pdf which can be passed to any of the extension apps. The problem here is, the sharing mechanism is available from iPhone 6s where 3D Touch is available and  we want to add our application as Printer and should be seen as Select Printer option on the Print page. This looks very promising though. I have attached the screen shots for the same.

Click on Print extension to share what you have opened on safari page :

[image: Click on Print extension to share what you have opened on safari page]

See your application as one of the option on Select Printer:

[image: See your application as one of the option on Select Printer]

Comment: You want to be a printer? Those are network printers - you can't hook into them. Why not *add your app as a share sheet item* which does the work - that's the way Apple wants you to do it.

Comment: You can do it on devices without 3D Touch too. Simply use two fingers to zoom into the preview in the print dialog and then you can save the PDF

Comment: Thanks for the info. But looks like this works only on iOS 10 onwards

Answer (score 0):

The menu you refer to will only show currently available airplay printers and no apps.

Instead, you would have to create a **action extension** for your app. Just like the Printer Pro app is doing:

[image]

For how to create such an extension follow these resources:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iOS_8_Action_Extension

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html

Comment: I have already tried creating action extension to get the pdf file from safari page, but no success. All you get is either a url or html from safari page to your extension app which when loaded on uiwebview can generate pdf file but both method has some or the other problem.

Comment: Maybe like this?: Depending on what Safari is displaying already (pdf or website) you get a path from the share sheet (a URL to a pdf file or to a website). Then you can use this path to download the pdf in your app and finally print it or if it is a website you open the URL in a webview and use some library like https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator to generate a PDF out of the website. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Let me try to simplify it. I open a https url like Facebook or linkedin etc with login credentials on safari and reach to homepage. Now I want to save the page as pdf file into my iOS application.

Comment: I have tried few solutions but no success.                                                       1) Able to get the url link of the safari but the problem is if the url is a user credential based then it would redirect to the login page when loaded on UIWebview. 2) Able to fetch the html string but the problem is that the html might have some external iFrame and not load the entire content of the page properly.

Comment: Ok, that is a problem. It seems the only way is via the iOS print dialog (in your screen) and then sharing the PDF to your app with an action extension. As Paulw11 mentioned it works with all devices, but it is a pretty bad user experience :(